# Why do error "A component is changing a controlled input of type hidden to be uncontrolled" occurs?

Tags: reactjs

I have problem with error "A component is changing a controlled input of type hidden to be uncontrolled". As I read this is the problem with default value of textfield not set. But in my case it is set but the error still occurs and the states part1, part2, operator are undefined.

I do now understand why, can somebody help with it?

class ConditionComponent extends React.Component {

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        operator: "",
        part1: "",
        part2: "",
        arr: this.props.arr
    }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.arr !== this.state.arr) {
        this.setState({
            arr: nextProps.arr, part1: this.state.arr[this.props.index].part1,
            part2: this.state.arr[this.props.index].part2,
            operator: this.state.arr[this.props.index].operator
        }, () => console.log(this.state.part1, this.state.part2, this.state.operator))
    }
}

handleChanges = (e, part) => {
    if (part === "part1") {
        this.setState({part1: e.target.value}, () => this.props.handleChange(this.state.part1, part))
    }
    if (part === "part2") {
        this.setState({part2: e.target.value}, () => this.props.handleChange(this.state.part2, part))
    }
    if (part === "operator") {
        this.setState({operator: e.target.value}, () => this.props.handleChange(this.state.operator, part))
    }
};

render() {

    return (
        <ListItem>
            <TextField
                fullWidth
                margin="auto"
                defaultValue={this.state.part1}
                onChange={e => {
                    this.handleChanges(e, "part1")
                }}
            />
            <Select value={this.state.operator}
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={e => this.handleChanges(e, "operator")}
                    inputProps={{name: "data"}}>
                {this.props.operators.map((val, i) => {
                    return (<MenuItem value={val} key={i}>{val}</MenuItem>)
                })}
            </Select>
            <TextField
                fullWidth
                margin="auto"
                defaultValue={this.state.part2}
                onChange={e => this.handleChanges(e, "part2")}
            />
        </ListItem>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Try to add `value` prop for your `TextField` components

Comment: are you still having the problem? if so, can you share a codesandbox with the error?